# Why does navigation bar logo not display in master view

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm writing an iOS 7/8 app and want to display a logo in the center of the nav bar. I started with a Master/Detail project. Then I added code to change the titleView to a logo (see the following code). The logo displays on the detail page but not on the master page (the master page title is displayed). I've tried putting the code in the navigation controller and the view controller but I get the same result. Is there something else that needs to be set in the storyboard or navcontroller code?

```
    var logo = UIImage(named: "logo_sm.png")
    var logoView = UIImageView(image: logo)
    self.navigationItem.titleView = logoView
```

or in the view controller

```
    var logo = UIImage(named: "logo_sm.png")
    var logoView = UIImageView(image: logo)
    self.navigationController?.navigationItem.titleView = logoView
```

**EDIT**
I found a way to make it work. In the UIViewController I changed the code to:

```
    self.navigationItem.titleView = logoView
```

This references the view's navigationItem rather than the navigation controller's navigationItem.

Comment: I found a way to make it work. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet just works fine. I think the problem is you didn't add the image inside your target, I guess.

[image]

Make sure you checked the "Add to targets" option, when drag and drop your image file to the project.

Hope this helps, Happy coding :)

Comment: No, the image has been added to the project properly. It shows just fine in the "Detail" view, just not in the "Master" view.